# Sans-serif font in siunitx does not work with \electronmass

Tags: siunitx, sans-serif

As default font, I want to have a serif font (MinionPro in my case). But for figure and table captions I like to use a sans-serif font (MyriadPro in my case). If I want to give a mass in electron masses in the caption using `siunitx`, I encountered that it does not work. I am using the `detect-all` option for `siunitx` to let it recognize the font.

(M)WE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[minionint]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[sansmath]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Electronmass}{\text{\ensuremath{m_{\text{0}}}}} % My own definition

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

Normal text in MinionPro.

\begin{table}[b]
    \centering\sffamily\mathversion{sans}
    \begin{tabular}{ c >{\centering}m{6.0cm} c }
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
    Band & Angular Momentum Eigenstate & Basis Set \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
    a & b & c \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Captions in MyriadPro. siunitx problem: $E=\SI{2}{\electronvolt}$ (works), $m=\SI{14}{\electronmass}$ (does not work), $m=\SI{14}{\Electronmass}$ (does not work either).}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

I am somewhat confused by the way `siunitx` acts here.  I get the correct result if I take the definition of `\electronmass` from `siunitx` and put it through LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[minionint]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[sansmath]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Normal text in MinionPro.

{\sffamily\mathversion{sans}%
  Sans serif text $\text {\ensuremath{m_{\text {e}}}}$
  vs. $m=\SI{14}{\electronmass}$ }
\end{document}
```

Joseph Wright is in this forum, maybe he has an idea.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete the MinionPro package. However, in my document I use MinionPro as default serif and MyriadPro as default sans serif. I also want to be able to switch the math from serif (which is default) to sans serif (e.g. in captions). So loading MyriadPro with the math option is not what I want.

Comment: @DaPhil - I suggest you rephrase your question and add a **real** MWE with your needs (e.g., what you mean with captions).  It will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: I rephrased the question.