# Math font changing and siunitx?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, siunitx

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{trace}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/using-declaremathversion
% note: mathpazo.sty, lmodern.sty overrides normal, bold!
%%% New math versions
\DeclareMathVersion{lmnormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{lmbold}
\DeclareMathVersion{mpazonormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{mpazobold}
\newcommand\lmmath{\mathversion{lmnormal}}
\newcommand\lmboldmath{\mathversion{lmbold}}
\newcommand\mpmath{\mathversion{mpazonormal}}
\newcommand\mpboldmath{\mathversion{mpazobold}}

%%% Math symbol fonts
% lmodern.sty
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {lmnormal}{OML}{lmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {lmnormal}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{lmnormal}{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {lmbold}  {OT1}{lmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {lmbold}  {OML}{lmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {lmbold}  {OMS}{lmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{lmbold}  {OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
% add for \SI?
\SetSymbolFont{upright}   {lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
% mathpazo.sty
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {mpazonormal}  {OT1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{upright}     {mpazonormal}  {OT1}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {mpazonormal}  {OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {mpazonormal}  {OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{mpazonormal}  {OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}

\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {mpazobold}   {OT1}{ppl}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{upright}     {mpazobold}     {OT1}{zplm}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {mpazobold}     {OML}{zplm}{b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {mpazobold}     {OMS}{zplm}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{mpazobold}{OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}

%%% Math alphabets, at most 16 families
% lmodern.sty
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}

% mathpazo.sty
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{mpazonormal} {OT1}{ppl}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{mpazobold}   {OT1}{ppl}{b}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{mpazonormal}     {OT1}{zplm}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{mpazonormal}   {OML}{zplm}{b}{it}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35287/sans-serif-font-with-siunitx
% \SI % "By default, all text is typeset in the current upright, serif math font."
% \sisetup{detect-all} %

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont% change text font to lmodern
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr}%
% \sisetup{detect-all}

\makeatletter
This is Mathpazo font \math@version. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2; \mathrm{ms}$. $20$ ms, \fbox{\SI{20}{\meter\per\second}}

\mpmath
\def\defaultscriptratio{.76}
\def\defaultscriptscriptratio{.6}
% \sisetup{detect-all}

This is Mathpazo font \math@version. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2; \mathrm{ms}$. $20$ ms, \fbox{\SI{20}{\meter\per\second}}


\lmmath
\def\defaultscriptratio{.7}
\def\defaultscriptscriptratio{.5}
% \sisetup{detect-all}

This is LModern font \math@version. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2; \mathrm{ms}$. $20$ ms, %
% \traceon%
\fbox{\SI{20}{\meter\per\second}}%
% \traceoff

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

As is, the output with `pdflatex` is:

[image: test1.png]

The first two `\SI` are typeset with Mathpazo as expected (the first time because the math setup "leaks" since `mathpazo` is loaded last; the second time because `\mpmath`->`\mathversion{mpazonormal}` is explicitly requested). But once `\mathversion{lmnormal}` is requested, it has no effect on `\SI` - *even* if the `\mathrm` in the equation (the [equivalent of \mathup for upright text in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139699/equivalent-of-mathup-for-upright-text-in-math-mode)) is acknowledged (since it is typeset with the `lmodern` font).

If I enable all of the `\sisetup{detect-all}`, then the output is this:

[image: test2.png]

Now all of the `\SI` are typeset in `lmodern` - even if I expect the first two to be typeset with `mathpazo`?!

So what do I need to do, so when I switch the math font, also the `\SI` command is typeset with the same font?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a ton of `\trace`ing, I think I managed to solve it:

[image: test3.png]

... but I'm quite puzzled by the solution, so a more erudite answer will be appreciated.

First, noticed this in the trace:

```
\__siunitx_font_weight: ->\unboldmath \mdseries
\unboldmath ->\@nomath \unboldmath \mathversion {normal}
```

So regardless of which `\mathversion` you choose - `siunitx` will switch to `normal`, apparently every time it executes an `\SI` command.

So, we'd basically need to `\SetSymbolFont` anew for the `normal` math version, each time the font is changed; unfortunately that command is `\@onlypreamble` - so most of the code is actually a hack providing  `\ReSetSymbolFont` which would work anywhere.

The most puzzling aspect is that doing a `\ReSetSymbolFont{upright} {normal}` does nothing - and what actually seems to work is `\ReSetSymbolFont{operators} {normal}`. I really cannot tell - why would the `operators` (and only that font, apparently) have effect on `\SI`?

Anyways, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% patchcmd
\usepackage{trace}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/using-declaremathversion
% note: mathpazo.sty, lmodern.sty overrides normal, bold!
%%% New math versions
\DeclareMathVersion{lmnormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{lmbold}
\DeclareMathVersion{mpazonormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{mpazobold}
\newcommand\lmmath{\mathversion{lmnormal}}
\newcommand\lmboldmath{\mathversion{lmbold}}
\newcommand\mpmath{\mathversion{mpazonormal}}
\newcommand\mpboldmath{\mathversion{mpazobold}}

%%% Math symbol fonts
% lmodern.sty
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {lmnormal}{OML}{lmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {lmnormal}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{lmnormal}{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {lmbold}  {OT1}{lmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {lmbold}  {OML}{lmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {lmbold}  {OMS}{lmsy}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{lmbold}  {OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}
% add for \SI?
\SetSymbolFont{upright}   {lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n}
% mathpazo.sty
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {mpazonormal}  {OT1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{upright}     {mpazonormal}  {OT1}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {mpazonormal}  {OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {mpazonormal}  {OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{mpazonormal}  {OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}

\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {mpazobold}   {OT1}{ppl}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{upright}     {mpazobold}     {OT1}{zplm}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {mpazobold}     {OML}{zplm}{b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {mpazobold}     {OMS}{zplm}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{mpazobold}{OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}

%%% Math alphabets, at most 16 families
% lmodern.sty
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{lmnormal}{OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmss}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{lmbold}  {OT1}{lmtt}{m}{n}

% mathpazo.sty
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{mpazonormal} {OT1}{ppl}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{mpazobold}   {OT1}{ppl}{b}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{mpazonormal}     {OT1}{zplm}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{mpazonormal}   {OML}{zplm}{b}{it}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35287/sans-serif-font-with-siunitx
% \SI % "By default, all text is typeset in the current upright, serif math font."
% \sisetup{detect-all} %

% latex.ltx - \SetSymbolFont
\makeatletter
% \cdp@list ->\@latex@error {Can be used only in preamble}\@eha
% \SetSymbolFont@ ->\@latex@error {Can be used only in preamble}\@eha
% \version@list ->\@latex@error {Can be used only in preamble}\@eha
% \group@list ->\@latex@error {Can be used only in preamble}\@eha
% \get@cdp ->\@latex@error {Can be used only in preamble}\@eha
%
% just a \let seems enough for this:
\let\Recdp@list\cdp@list
% no need for this:
% \expandafter\def\expandafter\Recdp@list\expandafter{\cdp@list}%\show\Recdp@list
%
\let\Reversion@list\version@list
\let\Regroup@list\group@list
\let\Reget@cdp\get@cdp
%
% \expandafter\def\expandafter\ReSetSymbolFont@\expandafter{\SetSymbolFont@}\show\ReSetSymbolFont@ % fails w 'Argument of \SetSymbolFont@ has an extra }.'
%
% \tracingpatches
% \let\ReSetSymbolFont@\SetSymbolFont@
% \patchcmd{\ReSetSymbolFont@}{\version@list}{\Reversion@list}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failure}} % -- macro cannot be retokenized cleanly; failure
%
\def\ReSetSymbolFont#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
 \@tempswafalse
 \edef\reserved@b{#3}%
 \def\cdp@elt##1##2##3##4{\def\reserved@c{##1}%
      \ifx\reserved@b\reserved@c \@tempswatrue\fi}%
 \Recdp@list%\cdp@list
 \if@tempswa
  \expandafter\ReSetSymbolFont@
    \csname mv@#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname#3/#4/#5/#6\expandafter
    \endcsname \csname sym#1\endcsname
 \else
  \@latex@error{Encoding scheme  `#3' unknown}\@eha
 \fi
}
% \@onlypreamble\SetSymbolFont
% \def\@onlypreamble#1{%
%   \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter{%
%        \@preamblecmds\do#1}}
%
\def\ReSetSymbolFont@#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\in@\expandafter#1\expandafter{\Reversion@list}%
  \ifin@
    \expandafter\in@\expandafter#3\expandafter{\Regroup@list}%
    \ifin@
      \begingroup
        \expandafter\Reget@cdp\string#2\@nil\reserved@a
        \toks@{}%
        \def\install@mathalphabet##1##2{%
             \addto@hook\toks@{\install@mathalphabet##1{##2}}%
            }%
        \def\getanddefine@fonts##1##2{%
          \ifnum##1=#3%
             \addto@hook\toks@{\getanddefine@fonts#3#2}%
             \expandafter\Reget@cdp\string##2\@nil\reserved@b
             \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\else
                \@font@info{Encoding `\reserved@b' has changed
                    to `\reserved@a' for symbol font\MessageBreak
                   `\expandafter\@gobblefour\string#3' in the
                    math version `\expandafter
                    \@gobblefour\string#1'}%
             \fi
             \@font@info{%
                Overwriting symbol font
                `\expandafter\@gobblefour\string#3' in
                 version `\expandafter
                \@gobblefour\string#1'\MessageBreak
                \@spaces \expandafter\@gobble\string##2 -->
                         \expandafter\@gobble\string#2}%
          \else
             \addto@hook\toks@{\getanddefine@fonts##1##2}%
          \fi}%
         #1%
         \xdef#1{\the\toks@}%
      \endgroup
    \else
       \@latex@error{Symbol font `\expandafter\@gobblefour\string#3'
                  not defined}\@eha
    \fi
  \else
    \@latex@error{Math version `\expandafter\@gobblefour\string#1'
       is not
       defined}{You probably misspelled the name of the math
       version.^^JOr you have to specify an additional package.}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont% change text font to lmodern
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr}%
% \sisetup{detect-all}
% \mathversion{normal}% just testing
% \traceon
% \ReSetSymbolFont{upright}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n} % lmnormal; nope
\ReSetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n} % lmnormal - this is the one, that seemingly works?

\makeatletter
This is Lmodern font \math@version. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2; \mathrm{ms}$. $20$ ms, \fbox{\SI{20}{\meter\per\second}}

\mpmath
\def\defaultscriptratio{.76}
\def\defaultscriptscriptratio{.6}
% \sisetup{detect-all}
% \ReSetSymbolFont{upright}     {normal}  {OT1}{zplm}{m}{n} % mpazonormal; nope
\ReSetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}  {OT1}{ppl}{m}{n} % mpazonormal

This is Mathpazo font \math@version. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2; \mathrm{ms}$. $20$ ms, \fbox{\SI{20}{\meter\per\second}}


\lmmath
\def\defaultscriptratio{.7}
\def\defaultscriptscriptratio{.5}
% \sisetup{detect-all}
% \ReSetSymbolFont{upright}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n} % lmnormal; nope
\ReSetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{OT1}{lmr} {m}{n} % lmnormal

This is LModern font \math@version. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2; \mathrm{ms}$. $20$ ms, %
% \traceon%
\fbox{\SI{20}{\meter\per\second}}%
% \traceoff

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: I stumbled also over this; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244944/76063).